# How to show two different photos as turtles?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to import two different pictures and show them in a line using Turtle (when I'll manage to do so they are supposed to move) but I can't find a way to show them together, the last picture I assigned to the turtle and the screen is taking over.
This is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from PIL import Image

screen = Screen()
height = 200

def create_players(height):
    player = Turtle()
    pic_name = input('write exact photo name: ')
    image = Image.open(pic_name)
    new_image = image.resize(((30, 30)))
    pic_resized = 'pic_resized.gif'
    new_image.save(pic_resized)
    screen.addshape(pic_resized)
    player.shape(pic_resized)
    player.penup()
    player.goto(-250, height)
    return player


player1 = create_players(200)
player2 = create_players(150)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
pic_resized = 'pic_resized.gif'
new_image.save(pic_resized)
screen.addshape(pic_resized)
```

You've pointed *both* turtle images to the *same* file.  We simply need to make sure the resized image file name is *unique*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from PIL import Image

def create_players(height):
    pic_name = input("Write exact photo name: ")
    image = Image.open(pic_name)
    new_image = image.resize(((30, 30)))
    pic_resized = pic_name + '_resized.gif'
    new_image.save(pic_resized)
    screen.addshape(pic_resized)

    player = Turtle()
    player.shape(pic_resized)
    player.penup()
    player.goto(-250, height)

    return player

screen = Screen()

player1 = create_players(200)
player2 = create_players(150)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling with pointers in python. It's complicated relatively to C. can you recommend a good place to look in to it?

Comment: @ArielMantel there's nothing to do with "pointers" here. Python does not have any such concept as a pointer as far as I know. Objects are passed by reference. Anyway, the phrase "pointed", in this context, just means that the value of the variable called `pic_resized` *contains* the same string value, regardless of what `pic_name` was. Meaning that when you pass its value to `player.shape()`, both player objects will now load the same image after `screen.exitonclick()` is executed, because they now both *contain* the same string value of the image file name.